Wife's residence permit after changing my Blue Card to Niederlassungserlaubnis (permanent residency)
I just changed my German blue card to German Niederlassungserlaubnis as my blue card was about to expire in 4 months. My wife is living in Germany since 2 years and has a normal residence permit as she joined me here on family re-unification visa 2 years back. How should I now proceed with her residence permit as her residence permit also expires in 4 months? Does she need an A1 certificate now to extend her Visa as I don't have a blue card anymore? I am worried now if I did a mistake converting my blue card as she doesn't have the required German skills.
